# Read string between two character

Tags: batch-file

I have one file with 31899 line and I only want to print string betwwen [] symbols how can I do that.I only want test and test 2 strings.

```
[TEST]
var=15
[TEST2]
dex=78
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of small errors in Magoo's answer, try one of these instead.

Batch File, *(current directory contains artmd.ini)*:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=[]" %%A In ('Find "["^<"artmd.ini"') Do @Echo=%%A
```

Command prompt, *(current directory contains artmd.ini)*:

```bat
For /F "Delims=[]" %A In ('Find "["^<"artmd.ini"') Do @Echo=%A
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk-specific solution:

```
gawk 'match($0,/^\[(.*)\]/, ary) { print ary[1]}' < yourFile
```

Comment: I tried this one on ubuntu but I cant see anything. I opened new doc  `#!bin/bash gawk 'match($0,/^\[(.*)\]$/, ary) { print ary[1]}' < artmd.ini`

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe your file has CRLF line endings. I removed the `$` from the pattern. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ('find "[" "filename" ') do echo %%a
```

(as a batch line - reduce each `%%` to `%` to run directly from the prompt)

for every line that contains `[`, extract the first token delinted by the two nominated characters.

Assumes all instances of `[` are as shown in the sample.

Comment: I used this command within .bat file like this `for /f "delims=[]" %%a in (`find "[" "artmd.ini ') do echo %%a `` but I cant see anything from my file "artmd.ini".

Comment: The quote before `find` was incorrect - it should be a single-quote, not a backquote. Sorry - not used to this keyboard...

Comment: Also, `?` changed to `"` - obviously, `filename` needs to be changed to the subject filename.